# How can I make chown work recursively?

Tags: unix, permissions

I've got a directory called  `pdfs` that contains a bunch of sub- and sub-sub-directories. I want to change ownership on all PDF files in all of the subfolders. I just tried this:

```
chown -R someuser:somegroup *.pdf
```

...but it didn't change ownership of the PDFs in subdirectories. The user and group do exist.

According to the man page for `chown`, the `-R` should mean recursive:

```
-R, --recursive
          operate on files and directories recursively
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 396, accepted):

Recursive mode only works on directories, not files.  By using the glob '*.pdf' the shell is passing the file list to chown, which sees these are files, and changes the permissions on the files it sees, and that's it.

Remember, in shells, the glob is evaluated by the shell, not the command.  If the glob matches files, they are passed to the command and the command never knows a glob existed.  (This is different than how Windows Command prompt used to do things).  If you have a dir, with the contents something like:

```
machine:$ ls -F
file1.pdf  file2.pdf  other.txt  subdir/
```

And you typed:

```
chown -R someuser:somegroup *.pdf
```

The shell would first make the list:
file1.pdf file2.pdf

and then run your command:

```
chown -R someuser:somegroup file1.pdf file2.pdf
```

See, there's no directory for -R to act on. It does what you asked it - change ownership on the two files on the command line, ignoring that quirky -R flag.

To do what you want, to use the '*.pdf' as a pattern for this directory and subdirectories, you can use `find`, which can find files that match a filename pattern (or many other criterea) and pass to a subcommand

```
find . -type f -name '*.pdf' | xargs chown someuser:somegroup
```

This starts in current dir '.' to look for files (filetype f) of name pattern `'*.pdf'` then passes to xargs, which constructs a command line to chmod.  Notice the quotes around the pattern `'*.pdf'`, remember that the shell will create a glob if it can, but you want the pattern passed to `find`, so you need to quote it.

Because filenames may have spaces in them, you want to use a trick to make it filename-with-spaces safe:

```
find . -type f -name '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 chown someuser:somegroup
```

In bash 3 and lower, this is the way you need to do it. More powerful globbing is available in bash 4 (with `shopt -s globstar`)and other shells.  The same in zsh, using a recursive glob `**`:

```
chown -R someuser:somegroup ./**/*.pdf
```

Comment: Edited to reflect that bash 4 with `shopt -s globstar` does recursive globbing.

Comment: Per the man page shown by the original poster, I found the chown -R did indeed change owner on folders AND files. No need for find. Using Mint 15.

Comment: @gwideman I know this is old... But yes, of course -R does recursive. The OP just had an issue with a very specific type of recursion, an extension and "file type is file" filtered one

Comment: @RichHomolka Ah. OP said the files were in a directory called 'pdfs', so I assumed the problem was in how to specify pdfs as the directory to recurse, and that all contained files were pdfs, so no need to select them specifically. But you may well be right, if the job is to select only pdf files, and leave others unchanged.

Answer (score 93):

```
chown -R someuser:somegroup /your/folder/here/*
```

This will apply chown to all files and all subdirectories and sub-subdirectories of the specified folder. Use with care.

Comment: Somehow `sudo chown -R user ./` worked for me, but `sudo chown -R user ./*` didn't

Comment: I know this is old, but though this answers the headline, does not answer the question. This is actually slightly worse than what OP had already tried.

Comment: @RichHomolka Having been brought here just because of the question title, I am quite happy to find this answer.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier fair enough. If this answer works for you I’m very happy. But it wouldn’t have worked for the original question.

Comment: This seems not to work for dot files such as `.env`.

Comment: This worked for my hidden files ("dot files")

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `find` utility:

```
find . -name '*.pdf' -exec chown someuser:somegroup {} +
```

Please don't forget the quotes around `*.pdf`. Otherwise the shell will try to expand it. This means already the shell will replace `*.pdf` with the names of all PDF files found in the current directory. But that's not what you want. You want to find the PDF files located in subdirectories. Btw.: That's also the problem with your `chown` command.

Comment: I had to look up the `+`, neat trick for performance. `-exec command {} +` This variant of the -exec action runs the specified command on the selected files, but the command line is built by appending each selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the command will be much less than the number of matched files. The command line is built in much the same way that `xargs` builds its command lines. Only one instance of `{}` is allowed within the command. The command is executed in the starting directory.

Comment: @PatrickM one (minor) other advantage to + vs ; .... plus isn’t a shell meta character and doesn’t have to be escaped

Answer (score 6):

The command

```
chown -R someuser:somegroup *.pdf
```

will only recurse down directories if the *directory* name ends in .pdf. You need something like:

```
find . -name "*.pdf" -exec chown someuser:somegroup {} \;
```

Comment: Technically it will only go to one level down. whether you call that true recursion or not is an exercise for the user :)

Answer (score 2):

to change the ownership of a directory recursively simply use:

```
sudo chown -R <username>:<groupname> <dir name>
```

here username = the new user who should be owner of directory

groupname = the new group which should be owner of directory

every file/directory has a user owner and a group owner

Comment: This does not do what the OP asked. This changes ownership of everything, OP asked for a specific set of files.

Answer (score 0):

I use `tree` instead:

```
 sudo tree -fai ~/.blabla  | xargs -L1 -I{} sudo chown youruser:youruser {}
```

Also take care to not run recursive chown or chmod on '/' directory or other system directory.

Answer (score 0):

To become the owner of all files in a directory, use

```
find directory -type f -name '*' | sudo xargs -d '\n' chown $USER
```

instead of

```
sudo chown $USER directory\*
```

or

```
sudo chown --recursive $USER directory
```

which might not work if there are too many arguments produced by * (too many files in the directory) or which does not not do what you want respectively.