# grep does not recurse for files with a specific extension

Tags: grep

Whenever I use grep with [gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)'s recurse option `-r` and include a glob pattern for files to search (e.g. `*.c`), no files in the subdirectories are searched.  I am using the latest grep from gnuwin32.

Specifically, I was searching for the string "iflag" in all my c source files in a directory.

```
grep -r iflag *.c
```

Comment: Can you give the exact command you are trying to execute?

Comment: I've updated at your request.

Comment: [Possibly related](http://superuser.com/questions/260925/how-can-i-make-chown-work-recursively/260939#260939): -r and file globs don't do what you want usually.

Comment: If you ask me, if the wildcard isn't supported for recursion, we should at least get an error or warning. Maybe it's too late to add a feature like this to such an old, important application, but a warning would be good. I think the "rpl" command has the same problem, it can't handle *.whatever recursively.

Comment: For future people wanting an example: grep "foo" --directories=recurse . --include="*.c"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Grep's `-r` option (which is the same as the `-R`, `--recursive`, `-d recurse` and `--directories=recurse` options) **takes a directory name (or pattern) as its argument**. The command you are trying to execute should be interpreted as "Starting in the current working directory recurse all directories matching the pattern *.c. In each of those directories search all files for the string iflag."

The grep command the OP probably wanted is

```
grep --include \*.c -r iflag .
```

which is interpreted as, "Starting in the current working directory recursively search all subdirectories. In each subdirectory search all files matching the pattern *.c for the string iflag."

Comment: If you make "takes a directory name (or pattern) as its argument" bold I'll make your answer the accepted answer.  I thought the `-r` option searched through the current working directory automatically.  Thanks!

Comment: I tried -r and -R and --directories=recurse, neither found matches in a subdirectory. Please add an example, because `grep -r "whatever" *.php` does not work  `grep -r . "whatever" *.php` does not work. I always assumed a mature application like grep would not have such a fatal flaw, I've been using it for over a decade, how did I miss this? It was just luck that I was in a subdirectory and found matches that were not found via the parent directory. Oddly, the "--include" solution works perfectly. I'm using CentOS 6.

Comment: If you can show a working example, I'll retract my downvote. But this does not work. Sorry. The other answer works. If you told me this works, I would take your word for it, because it's grep. And yet, it doesn't work. Strange.

Comment: @PJBrunet your issue is basically the same as the OP. Grep doesn't work the way you (and I) think it should. if you want to recursively search the current directory for the string "whatever" but only in files matching the pattern "*.php" then your command would be `grep -r whatever . --include *.php`

Comment: Good thing I found this answer.  The grep v3.1 I am using via git-bash on windows does not indicate that it requires a directory name as an argument.  "-r, --recursive           like --directories=recurse"

Answer (score 7):

<strike>I'm not sure why the recurse flag doesn't work, but here's a workaround that works for me.</strike>  The `-r` option takes an argument: the directory to search.  To search the current directory, give it the argument `.`.  For example

`grep regexp-to-find -r . --include=*.c`

#### Edit

**This is actually the expected behavior of grep**, and has nothing to do with running it on Windows.  The `-r` option takes a directory argument.  Check out HairOfTheDog's answer for why.

Comment: If anyone else has a better answer (this does not include suggesting just switching to cygwin, heh) I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: However, nobody ever explained why the '-r' option needs to be after the pattern which seems contrary to the grep documentation.

Comment: (1) "The `-r` option takes an argument: the directory to search" – Not really true for many common implementations of `grep`, where `-r` does not take any [option-argument](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_262). For them your `.` is an [operand](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_259), it may be specified last, not adjacent to `-r`. If fact it's more standard to specify operands after options. (2) One should quote or escape `*` here, to tell the shell not to try to expand it.

Answer (score 1):

I find the answers given so far way too complicated. Just use:

```
grep -r --include="*.c" searchString .
```

(as proposed by *christangrant* on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively) or by *HairOfTheDog*  in the comments above.)

If you are too lazy to type that all the time, just define a function and add it to "~/.bashrc". (A normal alias is not possible since parameters are used, as explained on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131670/make-a-bash-alias-that-takes-a-parameter))

```
rgrep() {
  grep -r --include="$2" "$1" .
}
```

Now you have an easy to use recursive grep. E.g., if you want to search for "string" in all text files, use:

```
rgrep string "*.txt"
```

Comment: I don't really like that one has to add quotes around the file type. If it is possible without, and anybody knows how to alter the function, please do so!

Answer (score 1):

#### Solution

For what you want to do, using `--include` is the right way; credit goes to other answers.

---

#### Rationale behind this answer

No answer posted so far has explained *why* your original code does not work like you expected. This is the gap my answer tries to fill.

---

#### Why your code does not work like you expected

Your original code is:

> ```
> grep -r iflag *.c
> ```

and you expected `grep` to recursively (because of `-r`) examine the current working directory and consider only files matching the pattern `*.c`.

To understand what happens, it's good to analyze first how this command behaves in Linux. You mentioned GnuWin, your OS is Windows, you probably used `grep` inside `cmd.exe`; this brings some interesting nuances (we will get to them), but still your `grep` is designed to mimic GNU `grep` in Unix/Linux.

So let's assume for a while you run the command in Linux. In Linux it works similarly, i.e. it does not give you what you expected either.

The first important thing that happens in Linux is the shell tries to expand `*.c` *before* it starts `grep`. `*.c` is expanded to possibly multiple arguments: names of matching files in the current working directory. E.g. if there are two matching files `foo.c` and `bar.c` then your command will effectively be:

```
grep -r iflag bar.c foo.c
```

Two important facts:

1. The above `grep` is not aware `*.c` was used. It sees `-r`, `iflag`, `bar.c`, `foo.c` as its arguments.
2. If `foo.c` and `bar.c` are regular files then `-r` is irrelevant. OTOH if e.g. `foo.c` is a [file](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690) of the type directory then `-r` will make `grep` descend into the directory; but `grep` will read all files in the directory (it is still not aware of `*.c` you typed).

In some shells you can use a glob that can match files in subdirectories. In your case it would be like `**/*.c`. This feature is called "globstar" and one may need to explicitly enable it in a shell. If you properly used such pattern, the shell would pass all matching paths to `grep` (e.g. `dir1/subdir/baz.c`), `grep` would not see the pattern itself, `-r` might be irrelevant. The job of picking all pathnames matching the pattern would be done by the shell. Your pattern is not like this though.

There are two scenarios where `grep` actually sees this `*.c`:

1. If there is no match in the current working directory then ([in some shells](https://superuser.com/a/1651872/432690)) `*.c` will not be expanded and it will be passed to `grep` literally as `*.c`.
2. If you escape or quote the asterisk in `*.c` (examples: `\*.c`, `"*.c"`, `'*'.c`) then it will not be expanded and the word will be passed to `grep` literally as `*.c`.

This cannot help you because `grep` itself is not designed to expand patterns in an argument it interprets as pathname. If it sees `*.c` where it expects a pathname then it will try to read a file named `*.c`. There are tools that actually interpret such patterns in some circumstances (in fact `grep --include` is an example).

Even if `grep` was designed to interpret this `*.c` in your code as a pattern in the way you expected, in many cases your code wouldn't work. You would need to quote or escape the pattern to protect it from the shell (see [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1217773/432690)).

In short, the reason your code doesn't work is `*.c` is expanded first (before `grep` runs), recursiveness starts later (when `grep` runs). You want the other way around and one method to do it is with `--include=*.c` (the other is with globstar where the shell handles the recursiveness, but it can give you `argument list too long` error; so it's better to let `grep` do this).

Note `--include=*.c` is still a pattern your shell may expand; if you want your code to be robust then you should escape or quote the asterisk. It's good to know what parts of your command (in general: any command) are (or may be) expanded by the (or a) shell.

---

#### Nuances of Windows

And now, finally, the nuances of Windows. Your `grep` in Windows is from the GnuWin project, it is designed to reasonably mimic the GNU `grep` you can find in Linux. We saw that in Linux your command results in `*.c` being expanded first, recursiveness starting later. In Unix/Linux `grep` cannot do anything about it because the tool starts after `*.c` is expanded by the shell. In Windows it's different.

If `grep` (`grep.exe`) is actually an executable in Windows and you run it in `cmd.exe` as

> ```
> grep -r iflag *.c
> ```

(like you probably did) then the executable *will* (be able to) see `*.c` before it gets expanded. In Unix/Linux `grep` (any executable in general) gets an array of arguments after a shell "digests" the command presented as a string. In Windows `grep.exe` (any executable in general) gets a *string* (a somewhat "digested" string, still a string), not an array; it creates an array for itself. In your case the string contains `*.c` and the expansion is done after `grep` starts, by `grep`; not before, not by `cmd.exe`. Like many tools in Windows `grep` probably doesn't bother to provide a custom function to get from a string to an array of arguments, some standard function provided by Windows is used, so *it looks* like `cmd.exe` does the job. Even the creators of your `grep.exe` pretend `*.c` in Windows is expanded by the shell; [here](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/install.html) they say "filename wildcards are interpreted by the command shell, not by the program". This is not entirely true. See the second part of [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1762573/432690) for some more details.

All this means *if* the creators of `grep.exe` wanted your *exact* command (with unquoted and unescaped asterisk) to behave like you expected (recursivity first, pattern matching later), then in Windows they could do this; in Linux they could not, not reliably, your shell would interfere unless you protected the asterisk from being expanded. Note an unquoted/unprotected `*.c` not being expanded by the shell is a non-standard behavior, even in Windows (where we should rather say "`*.c` not being expanded as if by the shell"). So even if *everyone* wanted your *exact* command (with *unquoted* and *unescaped* asterisk) to behave exactly like you expected (without interference from a shell, ever), then it wouldn't be implemented in GNU `grep` or GnuWin `grep.exe` anyway because it would be impossible in Unix/Linux and against the established standard in Unix/Linux and Windows.

It doesn't matter though, because the current behavior of `grep` (I mean interpreting filenames not as patterns, even if they look like patterns, even if `-r` is used) is fine and there is no need to change it.

Also note that the rules of quoting in Windows are different than in shells in Unix/Linux. `grep.exe`, when it gets a string, before the string is converted to an array of arguments, can see quotes used. By providing a custom function to convert from a string to an array, `grep.exe` could impose different rules of quoting, at least to some degree, possibly more Unix-like rules. The fact it doesn't impose such rules is yet another clue a standard function is used. It looks to me your `grep.exe` in Windows does in the most Windows-like way what a shell in Linux is responsible for (even though in Windows it has means to change some functionalities to Linux-like); and it does in the most `grep`-like way what GNU `grep` in Linux is responsible for.