# Zsh grep with glob * is not working

Tags: zsh, grep

The same command was working fine with bash

```
git show --pretty="" --name-only HEAD |  grep -i .*py
zsh: no matches found: .*py
```

Bash

```
git show --pretty="" --name-only HEAD  |grep -i .*py
api/client.py
```

Tried various options like escape with , passing -E
setopt +o nomatch.

Nothing is working so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's about [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html) that happens before the shell runs `grep`. It happens because there is unquoted, unescaped asterisk (`*`) in the command. Such asterisk is special to the shell.

When you try to run `grep .*py` and there is no file that matches `.*py` (note `.*py` is not treated as regex in this context, the dot is not special), basically two things can happen:

- The POSIX behavior is the shell runs `grep` with literal `.*py` as an argument. This is what you want. This is how the POSIX shell (`sh`) and compatible shells behave.
- Non-POSIX behavior is the shell detects there is no match, prints something like `no matches found: .*py` and doesn't run `grep` *at all*. This is how Zsh behaves by default. (For comparison: in Bash you can switch to this behavior by `shopt -s failglob`.)

If there was a match (in any shell), e.g. files named `.copy`, `.foo.py` etc., then `.*py` would be replaced with one or more words being names and `grep` would see them, not the literal `.*py` string. The command would do something you don't want (compare [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1217774/432690)). You don't want filename expansion, even if there is a match to `.*py`. Quote the string to suppress filename expansion. In this case it's enough to quote or escape `*` only. All these should work:

```
grep -i '.*py'
grep -i ".*py"
grep -i .'*'py
grep -i .\*py
```

I prefer quoting the entire argument. In some circumstances other possibilities are more useful, it's good to know there's more than one way.