# zsh fails to interpret a piped command which is OK with bash

Tags: bash, zsh, pipe, oh-my-zsh

```
~ ᐅ docker image inspect nginx | jq .[].Config.ExposedPorts
zsh: no matches found: .[].Config.ExposedPorts
```

With `bash` it works as expected.

I found out a [difference](https://riptutorial.com/zsh/example/19869/pipes-and-subshells) as to how the piping is interpreted in `bash` and `zsh`, but I can't say whether is has anything to do with my case.

Comment: The problem is not the pipe, it's the unquoted glob pattern. In bash, glob expansion can be controlled with [`shopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) and its various `*glob*` settings. You need to investigate how zsh does it.

Comment: tl;dr: quote the jq script: `jq '.[].Config.ExposedPorts'`

Comment: Similar: [Zsh grep with glob * is not working](https://superuser.com/q/1651869/432690). The mechanism of the "problem" is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Globbing also supports regex-like character group syntax. For example `[a-f]` matches `a`, `b`, … and `f`. It will only match a single letter. In your command, you have specified an empty group. It can never match anything.

In Bash, if a glob pattern doesn’t match anything, it is passed as-is on the command line. ZSH does not do this. Instead, it warns the user. You can change this: `setopt nonomatch`

tl;dr: Always quote your arguments if they contain anything but ASCII letters or numbers.

[This Q/A on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20037364/1025421) has some more details.