# Wildcard (*) is not matching files in another user's folders in zsh on macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

Logged in as user 1, I am trying to delete all files in a folder belong to user 2, using * as a wildcard. I know there is a file in the folder.

```
% sudo ls /Users/Guest/Documents
.localized    file
% sudo rm /Users/Guest/Documents/*
zsh: no matches found: /Users/Guest/Documents/*
```

Why is * not behaving as I expected?

Comment: Plus [this difference between `zsh` and other shells](https://superuser.com/a/1651872/432690), but not really relevant to the issue.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes thank you very much, I now understand the problem.