# Cygwin find returns "missing argument to `-exec'"

Tags: bash, cygwin, find

I have backups script that removes backups older than x days.

On Linux machine this is working well:

```
find /backups/dummy-prod-db -name "*_D_dummy-prod-db*" -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -v {} \;
```

But if I run this on Windows machine with Cygwin:

```
c:\cygwin64\bin\find.exe "C:\\backups\\dummy-prod-db\\" -name "*_D_dummy-prod-db*" -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -v {} \;
```

it returns

```
/usr/bin/find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

How can I fix it?

Edit:

I'm using CMD shell on Windows.

Comment: I don't have a cygwin to test on at the moment, but try quoting the braces: `-exec rm -v "{}" ";"`

Comment: @glennjackman `-exec rm "{}" \ ";"`  `-exec rm "{}" "\;"` not working. I found working solution, last backslash should be removed, see my answer below.

Comment: _I'm using CMD shell on Windows_ : Just to make sure: Are you joking here? You are writing bash commands, tag your question correctly as _bash_, and then pretend that you would execute this in a Windows CMD shell instead of a bash?? Please make clear, what you are using here, and how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [you have already found out](https://superuser.com/a/1762516/432690), the fix is to use `;` instead of `\;`. In my answer I will try to explain the mechanics behind this.

At first it's good to know why you need `\;` on Linux. It's not obvious, but `find` on Linux expects `;` (or `+`) as an argument somewhere after `-exec`, not `\;`; see the [specification from The Open Group](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/find.html), it says `-exec utility_name [argument ...] ;`. The backslash is for the shell. The problem is `;` is special for the shell, it's a command terminator. If you used `;`, the shell would interpret it as such, `find` wouldn't see it at all. To tell the shell `;` should not be treated specially we can escape it with a backslash (`\;`) or we can quote it (`";"` or `';'`). The shell will interpret and remove the backslash or the quotes and `find` will see sole `;` it expects.

The path `c:\cygwin64\bin\find.exe` you used makes me believe you were not working in Bash (or similar shell) in Cygwin, but rather in `cmd.exe`. In `cmd.exe` `;` is not special, so there is no need to escape it. Additionally `\` is not an escape character (`^` is). `\;` you used got to `find.exe` literally as `\;`. The tool did not find `;` (nor `+`) it expected, hence the error. Sole `;` gets to `find.exe` as `;` and this is what the tool expects.

AFAIK `";"` in `cmd.exe` should ultimately get to `find.exe` as `;`. `";"` works on Linux as well, so we can call `";"` "universal syntax" in the context of this problem. Note `';'` is not universal, single-quotes are not special in `cmd.exe`*.

---

* The situation is somewhat more complicated.

In Linux, executables like `find` get their arguments as an array (in your case: `find`, `/backups/dummy-prod-db`, `-name`, `*_D_dummy-prod-db*`, `-type`, `f`, `-mtime`, `+7`, `-exec`, `rm`, `-v`, `{}`, `;`). The shell handles word splitting and globbing (in your case there were no unquoted wildcards though), it removes quotes, backslashes.

In Windows, executables like `find.exe` get their arguments as a single *string*. AFAIK technically before the Windows system calls `main()`, it calls `_setargv()` to parse the command line into the standard C `argc` and `argv[]` arguments that it passes to the `main()` function of the program. The program can provide its own `_setargv()`. This means that interpretation of quotes and wildcards like `*`, and splitting to words (separate arguments) are really the job of each executable alone, not of `cmd.exe`. The executable may use some standard `_setargv()`, then it's almost like `cmd.exe` did the job, a situation similar to what is in Linux; or it may provide its own `_setargv()`.

Where I wrote

> `";"` in `cmd.exe` should ultimately get to `find.exe` as `;`

"ultimately" means "after `_setargv()`". Before `_setargv()` the quotes were there along with the rest of the command string; if `find.exe` provided a custom `_setargv()`, it could interpret these quotes in any way the author desired.

And where I wrote

> single-quotes are not special in `cmd.exe`

I really meant "not special for commonly used `_setargv()`". If `find.exe` provided a custom `_setargv()`, it could interpret single-quotes in any way the author wanted, e.g. like single-quotes in Bash. I don't know, *maybe* your `find.exe` does interpret single-quotes like this.

In general a phrase "something works (or doesn't work) in `cmd.exe`" includes `cmd.exe` *and* some standard `_setargv()`.

For comparison: `FIND` in Windows (the native `FIND`, *not* a port of *nix `find`) has its own peculiar syntax because it interprets the string it gets differently than any standard `_setargv()` would. You can find more information here: [Tcler's Wiki / exec quotes problem](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/exec+quotes+problem) (note some parts of the article are in the context of Tcl which has nothing to do with our problem, still the fragment about `FIND` is educative).

Comment: Thanks for such deep and clear explanation. Part about how executables get their arguments in Windows and Linux was very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I have found answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32377808/1215291

It says that backslash at the end should be removed. I changed this:

```
... -exec rm -v {} \;
```

To this:

```
... -exec rm -v {} ;
```

and it worked, but I don't understand why.

I would appreciate if someone could explain it.