# Can I find duplicate files with the same path in different locations?

Tags: bash, duplicate, deduplication

I have two folders/directories: `C:\MyData` and `C:\MyDataBackup` and the person that owns those two folders/directories and does not remember if they have edited the files in the original or in the Backup.

I want to get rid of `C:\MyDataBackup`, so I have to find all the files in there that are identical to their siblings in `C:\MyData` and delete them, and then have the owner handle the handful of remaining files manually.

How can I achieve that? The duplicate detection tools I have used so far usually have the shortcoming of...

- ...searching for duplicates *inside* `C:\MyData` and `C:\MyDataBackup` as well. That is not allowed! Those files must **not** be deleted, since they are intended. And since the data piles are *huge*, it would slow down the search for weeks.
- ...not doing complete byte-by-byte comparisons but just relying on hash sums.
- ...not sticking to the same path. Eg. they mark `C:\MyData\task1\done.txt` as identical to `C:\MyDataBackup\task1\done.txt` and `C:\MyDataBackup\task57\done.txt`.

So, how can I do a duplicates search

- in two folders/directories, finding only pairs over both and not within each
- with complete comparison (byte-by-byte)
- with restriction to the same path inside the respective folder/directory?

I am using Windows, but have Cygwin, so I can use bash magic as well.

(I've posted this question on StackOverflow today as well by accident)

Comment: You might look into using `rsync` for the comparison. How about `rsync -avn C:\MyData C:\MyDataBackup`. Output should be a file list of all changes.

Comment: WinMerge, https://winmerge.org/, is a free (Gnu license) comparison tool for diffing folders as well as files. See if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 2):

#### Preliminary note

Test the solution on some expendable pair of directories first.

---

#### Solution

This answer uses *nix tools. It should work in Cygwin. I mean in a shell (like `bash`) provided by Cygwin. (The shell is important, see [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1762511/432690).)

To be [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), I will use shell variables. If you ever need to apply this answer to other directories then it's enough to change the variables, while commands that follow are static. Use absolute paths. Run this snippet to set the variables:

```
reference='/cygdrive/c/MyData'
mutable='/cygdrive/c/MyDataBackup'
```

(Single-quotes are not necessary in this particular case; however users without experience who want to process directories with spaces in names will probably appreciate the quotes being already in the right places.)

You need to `cd` to the mutable directory. If the below command fails for any reason, abort.

```
cd -- "$mutable"
```

This is a command that does the real work:

```
find . -type f \
       -print \
       -exec test -f "$reference"/{} \; \
       -exec cmp -- {} "$reference"/{} \; \
       -delete
```

---

#### Explanation

- `.` defines our starting point, the [current working directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63081/108618). Thanks to the prior `cd` this will be the mutable directory. We don't use `"$mutable"` as the starting point, because we need `find` to consider relative paths so we can concatenate them with the path to the reference directory later. Our `find` will try to test all [files](https://superuser.com/a/1467109/432690) under (and including) `.`, descending to subdirectories of any depth.
- `-type f` is a test that checks if the currently considered file is a regular file. The purpose of this test is to avoid giving files of other types to `cmp` later. E.g. we don't want to use `cmp` with directories.
- `-print` prints the pathname of the currently considered file. This is only to give indication of progress; you can omit `-print` if you want.
- `-exec test -f "$reference"/{} \;` tests if there is a regular file under the same relative path in the reference directory. In the manual of GNU `find` `-exec … ;` is described as action, but it's also a test: it succeeds [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) the called executable (here `test`) returns exit status `0`, this is what we're relying on here. Our test is not only to avoid giving files of unexpected types to `cmp` later; it's also to:

  - avoid giving a nonexistent file to `cmp`;
  - avoid giving a symlink to `cmp` (see below).
- `-exec cmp -- {} "$reference"/{} \;` is a test that actually compares the two files. Note if `cmp` is given a symlink and the target of the symlink then it will tell you the contents are identical. In the context of your question: if `foo` in the reference directory is a symlink to `foo` in the mutable directory then `cmp` will make us think there are two copies, while the only copy is in the mutable directory and if we blindly believe `cmp` then we will delete it. Not giving symlinks to `cmp` (see above) solves this problem.
- `-delete` tries to delete the currently considered file. This action will be performed iff all the previous tests succeeded for the file.

---

#### Portability

AFAIK `find` in Cygwin is GNU `find`, it supports `-delete` which is a non-portable extension. GNU `find` also supports expanding more than one `{}` in `-exec`, as well as expanding `{}` concatenated with some string; these features are not portable. If you ever need a portable solution, use the below snippet. It's an alternative to the above, not an addition.

```
find . -type f \
       -exec sh -c '
          reference="$1"
          shift
          for f; do
             printf "%s\\n" "$f"
             test -f "$reference/$f" \
             && cmp -- "$f" "$reference/$f" \
             && rm -- "$f"
          done
       ' find-sh "$reference" {} +
```

---

#### Reasonable additions

Next you probably want to [delete empty directories](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8430/108618) from the mutable directory:

```
find . -type d -empty -delete
```

`-empty` and `-delete` are not portable. It's relatively easy to replace `-delete` (with `-depth` + `-exec rmdir -- {} \;`), [not so easy to replace `-empty`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/202243/108618), I won't elaborate.

Maybe you also want to delete symlinks and such. The following command tries to delete files, excluding directories and regular files:

```
find . ! -type d ! -type f -delete
```

Now the mutable directory (i.e. our current working directory) contains only a minimal directory tree with regular files that are candidates for manual inspection.

---

#### Notes

- In general there are race conditions ([TOCTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use)) that may allow a rogue user to make you delete a file in a wrong directory. E.g. see [*Race Conditions with `-exec`*](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Race-Conditions-with-_002dexec.html#Race-Conditions-with-_002dexec).
- In many places I used [`--`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/108618). If the paths in the variables are absolute and the starting point for `find` is `.` then `--` is not really needed. I decided to use `--` in case someone uses this answer as an inspiration and writes code where `--` may actually be useful.
- `find-sh` is explained here: [*What is the second sh in `sh -c 'some shell code' sh`?*](https://superuser.com/q/1526229/432690)

Comment: I haven't worked this through completely yet, but I think it is amazing. :-)

Comment: For the code in the "portability" section of your answer, is there a typo in the 5th line: `for f; do`?   
I'd expect it to read `for f in "$@"; do`.  Either way, this is an excellent answer with astounding detail!

Comment: @Randall There is no typo. Please run `sh -c 'for f; do echo "$f"; done' sh foo bar` and be surprised. Yes, it's official and documented, `"$@"` is the default array for `for`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Kamil Maciorowski is excellent.

Inspired by it, I have written a script for the 'find' command, which provides a little more comfort and error checking:

https://github.com/rdiez/Tools/tree/master/DeleteFilesIfDuplicatedInReferenceDir

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).