# How to pass a double quote as a command line argument in Windows CMD?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, windows-11

`argc` parameter in main function doesn't include redirection command [`<`, `>`], but I faced a confusing problem when using a double quote:

- **Shell: CMD**

  - I expected `argc` is `3` and `Yes!`:

    ```
    a.exe aa bb < input.txt
    ```
  - I expected `argc` is also `3` , **but `5`**, as I want to input double quote as argument:

    ```
    a.exe \" bb < input.txt
    ```

Comment: (1) What if you used `^"`? (2) What is `a.exe`? (3) Do you know what `_setargv()` this `a.exe` uses? What is it?

Comment: (1)argc is `2` and argv[1] is empty . (2)a.exe is simple program, print agrc. (3) i dont know that. i dont use it my code.

Comment: I don't know if it's still the case in Windows 11, but earlier in the Windows world even a "simple program" could impose its own syntax by providing or choosing `_setargv()`. See the second part of [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1762573/432690). I don't expect the situation has changed, so probably it's totally up to `a.exe` (i.e. up to `_setargv()` it uses), how exactly it splits the *string* you give it to an array of arguments, how it interprets quotes and escape characters, and what quotes and escape characters.

Comment: I would try `"^""`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: A program can choose between the two: Either handle the command-line as one string, or use argc as broken into tokens by the standard library.