# Remove all *.foo in directory tree

Tags: bash, rm

How do I remove all *.foo in a directory tree?

```
rm -r *.foo
```

does not work.

I could try a loop, but that needs recursive expansion:

```
for x in */*/.../*.foo
    do rm $x
done
```

Which is not possible either.

Comment: [How can I make chown work recursively?](http://superuser.com/questions/260925/how-can-i-make-chown-work-recursively) is basically the same question, except with `chown` instead of `rm`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `find`:

```
find -name '*.foo' -delete
```

Comment: Would this work? shouldn't it be `find . -name`?

Comment: @Rob, `man find`: _If  no paths are given, the current directory is used_.

Comment: @cYrus find is indeed really powerful. It lacks two actions that probably is easy to implement: *-callso youraction.so* and *-cfunc foo.c* . The shared object only needs to export a function void doIt(const char* path). That would be *really* powerful.

Comment: @user877329, there's the `-exec` action that can be used for that purpose.

Comment: @cYrus. Not really. It requires staring and stopping processes which is much slower. See mtak:s answer below.

Comment: @user877329, I see your point, but in my experience these tools are good for getting things done quickly and easily, but if you need to do it _right_ then you often have to start developing your own tool.

Comment: @cYrus thanks! I've been putting in `.` when I didn't need all this time! I'll save like, 20 seconds in the rest of my life now!

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a fairly recent version of bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
rm -- **/*.foo
```

Comment: Same with zsh, but you don't need the shopt.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using find:

```
find /dir/path -name *.foo -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `*.foo` be `'*.foo'`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest solutions would be to use the find command with the `exec` parameter:

```
find /path/where/to/start/search -type f -name "*.foo" -exec rm {} \;
```

This will look for all files named *.foo and perform rm {filename} for each one.

If you have lots of files, use of the `xargs` command may be faster:

```
find /path/where/to/start/search -type f -name "*.foo" | xargs rm
```

This will find all files, and will put the file names behind the rm command up until the max length of a command your distro/shell will support, so when run it'll to this:

```
rm dir1/file1.foo dir1/file2.foo dir1/file3.foo
```

As you can imagine now the `rm` binary needs to be started much less, making this a faster option.

Comment: Just to be safe, I'd suggest replacing `| xargs` with `-print0 | xargs -0`.  By default, xargs splits its input on any whitespace, which could produce unwanted results if any file or directory names had spaces in them. The extra switches make find and xmarks use null bytes, which are not allowed in filenames, as separators instead.

Comment: I'd just use the -delete flag.

Comment: Not all versions of find include the -delete flag (for example on Solaris <11), so using `xargs` or `-exec` is more universal.