# How to use globstar on bash older than v4

Tags: bash, redhat-enterprise-linux, javascript, globbing

We use this command to run all tests using [mocha](https://mochajs.org/): `mocha ./src/test/**/*.js --recursive`

Notice the double `**`. It works fine on any modern bash, except on the CI system which is a RedHat with `GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`.

I read that [v3 does not support double globstar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117826/bash-globstar-matching/156808#156808).

- I tried to [enable it](http://shellrunner.com/better-simpler-searching-and-scripting-with-bash-globstar/) by executing `shopt -s globstar`

  - but failed saying `shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name`.
- I asked the client's devops to update the bash

  - but he said "it doesn't show me that a new version of bash is available".
- This [other answer](https://superuser.com/a/260939/97034) was not helpful.

**Question: How can I execute a command with `**` on a linux bash v3.*? Any workaround?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it doesn't support globstar, then it doesn't support it.

However, most of the time you can adapt `find`, `xargs`, and/or similar tools. Your case is pretty simple, with everything under one directory, so:

```
find src/test -name "*.js" -exec mocha --recursive {} +

find src/test -name "*.js" -print | xargs -d '\n' mocha --recursive
```

(*find* puts the filenames in place of `{}`, and *xargs* appends them to the end. So in both cases, the repeated arguments must go at the end after all the --options, but that shouldn't be a problem for most programs.)

Alternatively, if running `mocha` *once for every file* is okay, then:

```
find src/test -name "*.js" -exec mocha {} --recursive \;
```

Compare `-exec … \;` (one file at a time) and the earlier `-exec … +` (as many as possible).

**Note:** In all above examples, the `"*.js"` has to be quoted because you want `find` to process it, not the shell.