# i need help reversing a chmod, chown and 'whoiam' code

Tags: chmod, chown

I used this code on an app:

chmod 600 /Applications/Freedom.app ; chown 'whoami':staff /Applications/Freedom.app

Does anyone know how to undo this?

Comment: so i go and log into my root account on my mac. i did look up what the 600 means, but does that help me with what previously was the permissions? or can i just set it to chmod 777(which means everyone has all permissions)as far as i know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To undo the chmod use :

```
sudo chown -R alexandertollman:alexandertollman   /Applications/Freedom.app
```

To set back to permission level 755 use :

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /Applications/Freedom.app
```

The `whoami` only prints the username associated with the current effective user ID.

Comment: Why did you make it recursive? You changed the permissions on a single file, so -R, is unnecessary

Comment: -R is for referencing the file

Comment: can someone explain what -R does? the only thing i know about it is when i looked up changing 'chown', it used -R for changing a group of files, the single file one did not have the -R in it.

Comment: I already told you what -R does, and it isn’t what you said it was: https://superuser.com/questions/260925/how-can-i-make-chown-work-recursively

Comment: -R is for referencing the file, * is used to use it on all pdfs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629046/linux-chown-r-parameter-what-does-it-mean

Comment: :( i got a downlike on my post
is it cause i had no idea what i was doing?

Comment: https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_1.3.0/gLSB/gLSB/chmod.html

Comment: @Ramhound oh I did not know that, but in pretty sure my answer works

Comment: It works on bother Unix and Linux

Comment: [-R and —reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HF4GS.jpg) is two entirely different things. [You shouldn’t take my word for it though, so read the manual, on the command and take your own word for it.](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) [Unix.com](https://www.unix.com/man-page/Linux/1/chmod/) would agree with me also.